# Developer console's CSS Selector returns wrong results

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-selectors

Using Firefox's or Chrome's developer console, When I type `$('a')`, It should return all the links on the page in an array (If I select the wrong frame it won't for example, but that is not the problem now). Please someone enlighten me, why do I get single `a` result using this CSS selector with both Firefox and Chrome on some sites and an array of `a`'s on others (both sites have more than one `a` tags)?

This worked before, I don't remember it ever not working like this. For reference let's take http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

My Firefox console result:
[image]
Chrome:
[image]

If I do this on stackoverflow, the CSS Selector works too. The Xpath works on every site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Chrome dev tools documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference):

> `$(selector)` returns the reference to **the first DOM element** with the specified CSS selector. This function is an alias for the `document.querySelector()` function.

So you get the expected behaviour on useragentstring.com.

On Stackoverflow you get different behaviour because jQuery has been included on the page and the `$` variable has been overwritten by [the jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) which (when called as a function):

> Accepts a string containing a CSS selector which is then used to match a **set** of elements.

Comment: Is there any way to call the default ones if they get overwritten? I could you the `$` for single and `$$` for the set results, but only if they don't get overwritten.